# Finding out watch duration of videos in Facebook feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to extract the video IDs and watching duration of the **watched** videos on Facebook for one specific user via the Graph API?

Answer (score 0):

With normal video objects, there's no way I know of. For the Open Graph action `videos.watches`, this might be possible:

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/video.watches/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.1#reference-user_actions_video